# I want to edit the spinner value in runtime in android application

Tags: android, spinner

Hai, I want to edit the spinner value in runtime in android application

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing in that

Comment: @schwiz please understand my question.i want edittable spinner.

Comment: sounds more like you want code written for you than a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you meant fill Spinner values runtime: there's nothing special in that Do smth like:

1) Instantiate `Spinner` thru xml resource

2) Get reference to Spinner object thru `Activity.findViewById()`

3) Define `Adapter` to your spinner :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

4) Fill adapter with desired values thru `adapter.add()`

If you meant make Spinner values editable as `EditText` it's a bit complicated.

i) You need to define your own styles instead of built-in styles `simple_spinner_item` and `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!--
  ~ my_simple_spinner_item.xml
  -->

<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mySimpleSpinnerItem"
    style="?android:attr/mySpinnerItemStyle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

ii) Then just apply those styles to your `Spinner`

Never checked but should work, at least I used to redefine styles for my Spinner in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Call `setSelection()` to change the selected item in the `Spinner`. Otherwise, there is no such thing as an "editable" `Spinner` in Android.

Answer (score 1):

In my question here:
[Android editable spinner plus virtual keyboard - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351639/android-editable-spinner-plus-virtual-keyboard-is-it-possible)
I placed working code for editable spinner. The only problem is with the virtual keyboard presence.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will helpful to you.

Try this Code..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner sp;
    EditText et;
    List<String> li;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        li=new ArrayList<String>();
        li.add("Item 1");
        li.add("Item 2");
        li.add("Item 3");

        sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        add();

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            li.add(et.getText().toString());
            et.setText(null);
            add();
            }
        });
    }

    private void add() {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,li);
        adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sp.setAdapter(adp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short & simple answer:**

```
final Spinner team = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.team_name);
team.setSelection(5); // To set 6th value in the list.
```